# How to find out which values correspond to a range in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I'm trying to find out which values in one of my dataframes are in-between values in another and based on that get data into a column.

let's say i have 2 dataframes, first one is:

| Name | Code | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 02050 |  |
| Samsung | 54004 |  |
| Kruger | 06001 |  |

second df:

| Activity | LEFT | RIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mobile | 01100 | 01700 |
| computers | 02000 | 03000 |
| cars | 03000 | 04000 |
| tv | 05000 | 10000 |

desired output:

| Name | Code | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 02050 | computers |
| Samsung | 54004 |  |
| Kruger | 06001 | tv |

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Apple","Samsung", "Kruger"),
                  Code = c("02050","54004", "06001"),
                  Activity = "")

df2 <- data.frame(Activity = c("Mobile","computers", "cars", "tv"),
                  Left = c("01100","02000", "03000", "05000"),
                  Right = c("01700","03000", "04000", "10000"))
```

I have been stuck on this the whole day. i have mainly tried using sqldf, left_join and which and keep getting errors. Can't understand why which() isn't working by simply doing something along the lines of:

```
df1[which(as.numeric(df1$code) < as.numeric(df2$RIGHT) & 
              (as.numeric(df1$code) > as.numeric(df2$LEFT) | 
               as.numeric(df1$code) == as.numeric(df2$LEFT) 
              ) 
         ),]...........etc
```

Comment: Using the `dplyr` package, we can do `left_join(df1, df2, by = join_by(between(Code, Left, Right)), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% mutate(Activity = if_else((is.na(Activity) | !nzchar(Activity)) & !is.na(Activity.y), Activity.y, Activity)) %>% select(-Activity.y, -Left, -Right)`. This is also supported in `data.table`, `sqldf`, and `fuzzyjoin`, see the dupe links for more examples using them.

Comment: it seems that i can't use join_by.

Comment: I solved the problem by using a loop on the between function

Comment: If you don't have `join_by`, that means you're on an older version of `dplyr`. A `for` loop might do most of what you need, I suggest it is inefficient at best. Good luck.